# Login Cakephp doesn't work with hashed password

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-1.2

I have a weird mistake when log in. The field 'passwd' is hashed as usual, so for instance the password '12345' is '844b1054b7c94519b6565dd301b3dede4a07b2c1' in the database.

Apparently everything is correct...

...but when I try to log in, I can do it with '844b1054b7c94519b6565dd301b3dede4a07b2c1', but no with '12345', and I don't know why. It should be the opposite!

```
$default_settings = array(
    'Auth.enabled' => true,
    'Auth.authorize' => 'controller', //actions
    'Auth.actionPath' => $prefix.'/',
    'Auth.userModel' => 'Taller',
    'Auth.authenticate' => ClassRegistry::init('Taller'),
    'Auth.fields' => array('username' => 'usuario', 'password' => 'passwd'),
    'Auth.authError' => false,
    'Auth.loginAction' => array('plugin' => 'pro', 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),                                       'Auth.loginRedirect' => '/webpro',                                  'Auth.logoutRedirect' => '/webpro',         
    'Acl.enabled' => true,
);
```

I'm using CakePHP 1.2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it give any error ?

Comment: No, just 'wrong password'. I guess is something in the configuration, but I don't know what.

Comment: btw you are using very antique version of cake

Comment: It should unhash the password before validate, but it doesn't.

Comment: Yes because the web page is an online shop, and I don't have support to change the version now.

Comment: Has anyone the same problem?

Comment: show your code please

Comment: I have exactly the same code than in localhost, and It works there perfectly. Don't know what are the mistake.

Comment: The password is only hashed automatically if both the username and password fields are in the submitted form data. Check your form and `$this->data` in your controller, there will be a mismatch with the Auth component config. Btw there's no indication what `default_settings` is, where or how it's used...

Comment: "It should unhash the password before validate, but it doesn't."... No - that's just not how it works.  You don't unhash passwords.

Comment: please verify db entry

Comment: That's true, sorry. I've said something I didn't want to say. I mean that the code doesn't understand that the password is already hashed in the DB.

Comment: The databade input is char(40), and it works in localhost...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CakePHP probably doesn't understand that it needs to hash the password field before comparing because you have renamed your field... This is confirmed by the fact that you can enter the hashed password into the field and login successfully...

```
 'Auth.fields' => array('username' => 'usuario', 'password' => 'passwd'),
```

Try renaming your database column to password, and make sure you are using FormHelpers in your views to rule out that being your issue.. I apologise for the poor answer, but this is the best I can make from what you have posted. If you reply to my answer I'm happy to improve it.

Otherwise, Find a way to Hash the passwords before comparing, but this is something the new >2.0 definitely does. I am not sure how to do this in CakePHP 1.2, but I strongly suggest you upgrade to enjoy all the new features in 2.0, also try stick to CakePHP conventions, the more you customise the harder issues become to diagnose.

## Update

### Try adding the following to your User Model:

**app/Model/User.php**

```
    function hashPasswords($data) {
        return Security::hash($data,'md5',false);
    }
```

**Ref:**
http://api.cakephp.org/1.2/class-Security.html

### If the above doesn't work:

Alternative Controller Based Approach

**app/Controller/UsersController.php**

```
function login() {
    if(!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->data['User']['password'] = Security::hash($this->data['User']['password'],'md5',false);
        $this->Auth->login($this->data);
        $this->redirect("home");
    }
}
```

**Ref:**
http://book.cakephp.org/1.2/en/The-Manual/Core-Components/Authentication.html

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I have tried to change the name of the column, but the problem is still there. 
I know that updating the vesrion of Cake should resolve lots of problems, but right now I can't do it.

So, I will keep triying and I will inform you when the issue has been solved. Thanks

Comment: I've updated my answer with how to hash, there is actually a number of ways to do the above, so it's up to you to find a more elegant way, but I am confident that based on what you have told us that my controller method will work.